# node.js socket.io emit not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've got the following config:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
var httpserver = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

var io = require('socket.io')(httpserver);

app.all('/blockcallback', function(req, res){

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");

    getTxSender(req.query.tx,function(ref_wallet){
          (..)
   });
   io.emit('status', {'message': 'done'});
   res.send('*ok*');
});
```

index.html

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
                    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
                        socket.on('status', function(datos){
                            alert('received');  
                        });
</script>
```

ok when i call `http://localhost:3000/blockcallback` looks like everything works perfectly, but i am not getting the 'status' call on the clientside.

my js console shows:

```
Error in event handler for extension.onRequest: undefined
Stack trace: undefined localhost/:1 
Error in event handler for extension.onRequest: undefined
Stack trace: undefined extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:9
Stack trace: undefined extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:9
```

I don't understand what's happening...

Regards,

Comment: When you do `io.emit()` who are you trying to send to?  All connected users?  Only the user making the request?  Also, do you realize that the way your code is structured, neither `io.emit()` nor `res.end("*ok*")` are waiting until `getTxSender()` is done?

Comment: I'd say one of the first things to do here is to do further debugging on those errors in the console and eliminate all of them.  Errors have a way of messing up other code, even sometimes unrelated code.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is you haven't waited for the connection yet...

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('status', { hello: 'world' });
});
```